# Using Lucene to index Wikipedia

Tags: java, lucene, mediawiki

Is it possible to use Lucene Benchmark to index a wikipedia dump? I want to be able to execute phrase queries on the latest english wikipedia page dump. I'm trying to look for example use cases but I haven't found any.

I downloaded the latest english dump, named: 
enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

Then I ran the command in the terminal:
java org.apache.lucene.benchmark.utils.ExtractWikipedia -i ~/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

which I believe extracted the pages into a directory labeled "enwiki"

Now is there something else in benchmarks that I need to run in order to index the wiki? The README.enwiki does not really give me a clear set of instructions, in fact I'm not even sure if I was supposed to run the ExtractWikipedia class or not.

Comment: This question seems to lie in the uncanny valley between StackOverflow ServerFault and SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run "ant"; I posted a more thorough answer on the Lucene mailing list, but that is basically the gist of it.  The build.xml file has a bunch of targets for running benchmarks.

Comment: Could you add a link to your answer in the Lucene mailing list or paste the answer here?  I would like to try this solution but there are no instructions.

Comment: Here's a link to that old thread from 2011: http://markmail.org/thread/qhkh7lyxff77kskr YMMV I'm not sure that the solution there is still valid since Lucene has undergone many changes since then...

Answer (score 0):

The Wikimedia Foundation has been working on new project called DiffDb. Using Hadoop we create the diff between two revisions and all those diffs are indexed using Lucene. You can find the code at github:

- Wikihadoop: https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop
- DiffDb: https://github.com/whym/diffindexer

The resulting index for just the English Wikipedia is 1.4Tb but you can do really cool queries, such as who added foo in april 2005, who removed more than 10k in bytes, etc etc.